# UIButton does not resize height correctly with custom font when sizeToFit is called

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

I'm attempting to create a `UIButton` using a custom font. I set the `titleLabel's` font and then set my text, then call `sizeToFit`. Unfortunately, it resizes the height to a couple of pixels too small and shaves off part of each capital letter. The button's `titleLabel` has a smaller height than the size of the button itself, but setting its frame manually after calling `sizeToFit` isn't doing anything for me. I noticed the same behavior from a plain `UILabel`, except when I manually set the frame to the size of my `UIButton`, the text displayed perfectly. When I called `sizeToFit`, the `UILabel` became the same size as the `UIButton's` `titleLabel`, and it also cut off the top of my capital letters. Additionally, since this was a `SpriteKit SKView` I was adding these buttons to, I also created an `SKLabelNode` to see how it dealt with automatically sizing the font, and it did a perfect job, with its height being several pixels taller than both my `UILabel` and my UIButton's `titleLabel` height. Here's an imgur album to show it visually, where it's noticeable on the S and the dotting of the lowercase i:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/47YaU.jpg

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem and comes across this, I figured out a solution simply by subclassing UIButton. Then, I just modified layoutSubviews so that the titleLabel bounds equaled the button's subviews, and it no longer cut off the top part of the font. Not sure if it's the best way, but it works.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.titleLabel.bounds = self.bounds;
}
```